# Fastest Integer Search for Any Arbitrary X and Y

Tags: python, algorithm, search, discrete-mathematics

With the application of Discrete Math, what's the fastest algorithm in python to solve this problem:

With the equation ***ax + by = d***, where ***a, b*** and ***d*** are user inputs, search for the integer value pairs for ***x and y*** in the range |***L, R***| (including ***L and R***) that satisfies the equation.

***L and R*** are user inputs as well.

Output all possible values for ***x and y*** in increasing order. Print ***none*** if there are no possible pairs.

Case 1:

```
a = 1
b = 5
d = 40
L = 0
R = 10

Result:
0 8
5 7
10 6
```

Case 2:

```
a = 14
b = 91
d = 53
L = 1
R = 100

Result:
none
```

Here's my code, but I believe there is a **much** faster way in searching. This is too inefficient.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
d = int(input())
L = int(input())
R = int(input())

isNone = True
for x in range(L, R+1):
    for y in range(L, R+1):
        if (a*x) + (b*y) == d:
            print(x, y)
            isNone = False
if isNone: print("none")
```

Can there be an algorithm with ***O(1)***? What's the fastest way?

Comment: Does the class you're taking have an accompanying discrete math text? Does it say anything about this (perhaps called something like "linear diophantine equations")?

Comment: Hi, never heard of that.

Comment: There's no need to loop over both `x` and `y`: given one of those values, you can easily calculate what the other one would have to be.  If that's an integer, and within the given range, you've found a solution.  This would be O(R-L) - an O(1) algorithm is not possible for a problem that can have an arbitrary number of solutions.

Comment: @jasonharper it can be solved in the complexity of O(gcd(a,b)), which is O(1) assuming all numbers are bounded. That's a [linear diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation).

Comment: @freakish I'm sorry, I'm kinda new in programming and I mostly do bruteforce to solve these types of problems. How does getting the gcd find all the pairs bounded by L, R?

Comment: @muw read the entire article I've linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity I imagine you want to apply is as follows (straight from wikipedia, though a similar phrasing should be found in most discrete math texts or could be proven on your own):

> The simplest linear Diophantine equation takes the form ax + by = c, where a, b and c are given integers. The solutions are described by the following theorem:

> This Diophantine equation has a solution (where x and y are integers) if and only if c is a multiple of the greatest common divisor of a and b. Moreover, if (x, y) is a solution, then the other solutions have the form (x + kv, y − ku), where k is an arbitrary integer, and u and v are the quotients of a and b (respectively) by the greatest common divisor of a and b.

This nearly immediately answers the question, especially since the standard proof of it uses something called the *euclidean algorithm*. In the interest of simplicity we're going to do the following:

1. Use the euclidean algorithm in the forward direction to find `g = gcd(a, b)`.
2. Backsolve through the euclidean algorithm to find `_x, _y` such that `_x*a + _y*b == g`.
3. If `d` isn't a multiple of `g` then there can't possibly be any solutions, so exit early.
4. Otherwise, `x, y = _x*(d//g), _y*(d//g)` is a possible solution. Use that to find all solutions in the desired range.

```
def gcd(a, b):
    # forward euclidean algorithm
    q, r, x, qs = None, b, a, []
    while x%r:
        (q, r), x = divmod(x, r), r
        qs.append(q)

    # save the gcd for later
    g = r

    # backsolve euclidean algorithm
    if not qs:
        return 1, 1-a//b, g
    theta, omega = 1, -qs[-1]
    for q in reversed(qs[:-1]):
        theta, omega = omega, theta - q * omega
    
    # theta * a + omega * b == g
    # g might be negative, but we don't care about a canonical solution
    return theta, omega, g

def idivide_zero(a, b):
    # integer division a/b, round toward 0 instead of round down
    q = a // b
    if q < 0 and b*q != a:
        q += 1
    return q

def bounded_solutions(a, b, d, L, R):
    _x, _y, g = gcd(a, b)
    if d%g:
        return

    # a*x + b*y == d
    x, y = _x*(d//g), _y*(d//g)

    # solutions are of the form (x+k*v, y-k*u)
    u, v = a//g, b//g

    # The next trick is to find all solutions in [L, R].
    # Basically, we need L <= x+k*v <= R and L <= y-k*u <= R.
    # Note that valid choices of k exist in a contiguous interval, so
    # we only have to find the lower and upper bounds to be able to
    # quickly enumerate all options.
    xb = sorted(idivide_zero(b-x, v) for b in (L, R))
    yb = sorted(idivide_zero(y-b, u) for b in (L, R))
    m, M = min(xb[0], yb[0]), max(xb[1], yb[1])
    for k in range(m, M+1):
        yield x+k*v, y-k*u

a = int(input())
b = int(input())
d = int(input())
L = int(input())
R = int(input())

empty = True
for x, y in bounded_solutions(a, b, d, L, R):
    print(x, y)
    empty = False
if empty:
    print('none')
```

**Code is untested.** It's right in spirit, but there may be some debugging left.

Comment: So far so good, but I'm still testing other cases. At the same time, I'm trying to understand every bit of your code, so thank you for the comments.

Comment: Sounds great. If anything is unclear, please point it out so that I can update the answer. I'd also highly recommend working out a couple euclidean algorithm examples by hand. [wolfram alpha](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanAlgorithm.html) has a decent intro. E.g., if we want the gcd of `150` and `84` we'd progressively divide and take the remainder: `150 % 84 == 66`, `84 % 66 == 18`, `66 % 18 == 12`, `18 % 12 == 6`, and `12 % 6 == 0`, yielding the sequence `150, 84, 66, 18, 12, 6, 0`. The last non-zero element is always the gcd. You can algebraically backsolve through the system of...

Comment: ...equations you're working on to set the gcd equal to some expression, substitute from the previous equation, and so on till you have coefficients of the form `gcd == _x*a + _y*b`. That process is exactly what our code is doing with `theta` and `omega` (work it out with a super small example to start with). From there, since if there is a solution it must be a multiple of the gcd, we can just multiply those coefficients by a suitable constant to get a single solution, and the discrete math theorem characterizes the rest of the solutions. The hard work was finding the first one.

Comment: Tried a LOT of test cases, flawless! Thanks for your great contribution good sir.